# Select top nth row in SQL gives wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `Product` and `SalesProduct`.

`Product` table sample records (here `ProductID` is the primary key):

```
ProductID | ProductCode | Name
----------+-------------+-----------
1               P001      Computer
2               p002      Laptop
3               p003      Speaker
```

`SalesProduct` table sample records (here `ID` is the primary key, and `ProductID` is a foreign key referencing the `Products` table):

```
ID| SalesNo | ProductID  
--+---------+-----------
1   S0001         1
2   S0002         2
3   S0003         3
4   S0004         1
5   S0005         2
6   S0006         3
7   S0007         1
8   S0008         2
9   S0009         3
```

When I write this query:

```
SELECT  
    SalesNo, SalesProduct.ProductID, Name 
FROM 
    SalesProduct
JOIN 
    Product ON SalesProduct.ProductID = Product.ProductID
```

it will work fine and return this result:

```
SalesNo | ProductID | Name
--------+-----------+---------
S0001         1       Computer
S0002         2       Laptop
S0003         3       Speaker
S0004         1       Computer
S0005         2       Laptop
S0006         3       Speaker
S0007         1       Computer
S0008         2       Laptop
S0009         3       Speaker
```

BUT when I try to select the `TOP(3)` rows like this:

```
SELECT TOP(3) 
    SalesNo, SalesProduct.ProductID, Name 
FROM 
    SalesProduct
JOIN 
    Product ON SalesProduct.ProductID = Product.ProductID
```

This query will return same product:

```
S0001   1   Computer
S0004   1   Computer
S0007   1   Computer
```

BUT I want this result:

```
S0001         1       Computer
S0002         2       Laptop
S0003         3       Speaker
```

What's wrong in the above query? And how can I get the expected output?

Comment: When you use `TOP` you should always use `ORDER BY`.  The results from a SQL query are in indeterminate order -- and that can change between executions.

Comment: Add `ORDER BY SalesNo` since that is the result you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff big thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the Expected output might be because you don't have an Order By Clause specified. You Can Do it either of the following

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    SalesNo, SalesProduct.ProductID, Name 
FROM 
    SalesProduct
JOIN 
    Product ON SalesProduct.ProductID = Product.ProductID
ORDER BY SalesNo ASC
```

Or Like This

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT 
RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  SalesNo),
        SalesNo, SalesProduct.ProductID, Name 
    FROM 
        SalesProduct
    JOIN 
        Product ON SalesProduct.ProductID = Product.ProductID

)
SELECT
SalesNo, SalesProduct.ProductID, Name 
WHERE RN<4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP(3) sp.SalesNo, sp.ProductID, p.Name 
FROM SalesProduct sp
INNER JOIN Product p ON SalesProduct.ProductID = Product.ProductID
ORDER BY sp.SalesNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE (ProductId INT,ProductCode VARCHAR(10), Name VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Product(ProductId,ProductCode,Name) 
(SELECT 1,'P001','Computer' UNION ALL SELECT 2,'P002','LAPTOP' UNION ALL SELECT 3,'P003','Speaker')

DECLARE @SalesProduct TABLE (Id INT,SalesNo VARCHAR(10),ProductId INT)
INSERT INTO @SalesProduct
SELECT 1,'S0001',1 UNION ALL SELECT 2,'S0002',2 UNION ALL SELECT 3,'S0003',3 UNION ALL SELECT 4,'S0004',1
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'S0005',2 UNION ALL SELECT  6,'S0006',3 UNION ALL SELECT 7,'S0007',1 UNION ALL SELECT 8,'S0008',2
UNION ALL SELECT 9,'S0009',3

SELECT TOP(3) 
    SP.SalesNo, SP.ProductID, P.Name 
FROM 
    @SalesProduct SP
INNER JOIN 
    @Product P ON SP.ProductID = P.ProductID
ORDER BY SP.SalesNo
```